# iGoogle Gadget on Android Phone as APP or Widget

Tags: android, android-widget, google-gadget, igoogle

I have added a gadget in my iGoogle to display orders from our e-commerce shopping cart. I would like to have it as a Widget for our Android phones.  Anyone know where to start and what needs to be done?  [Link To iGoogle Gadget](http://www.google.com/ig/directory?type=gadgets&url=www.brandlabs.us/v/vspfiles/downloadables/widgets/igoogle/volusion_order_notifications.xml)

I have found that I can EMBED the html to a webpage, could this be useful in creating something that would appear on my phone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on what you mean by "widget" or by "APP".

If by "widget" you mean "app widget" (interactive element of a home screen), what you want is not possible, unless you write your own home screen application.

If by "widget" you mean "widget" (element of an activity, subclass of `android.view.View`), you could create a custom subclass of `WebView` that knows the URL to your gadget and arranges to load in whatever extra HTML/JS/CSS is necessary to display that gadget in a browser outside of iGoogle.

If by "APP" you mean "Android native application", you could look at [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/). You would still need to identify whatever extra HTML/JS/CSS is necessary to display that gadget in a browser outside of iGoogle.