# How do I convert an iGoogle gadget into an Android widget?

Tags: android, android-widget, igoogle, code-translation

I'm trying to recreate this progress bar clock [gadget](http://www.google.com/ig/directory?dpos=top&root=/ig&url=hosting.gmodules.com/ig/gadgets/file/110063134793252420371/progress_bar_clock_0.xml) I built in [iGoogle](http://www.igoogle.com) as a widget for Android devices.

It seems like it should be pretty straightforward, especially considering the code is only 75 lines, but I have very little experience with developing in Android - even more-so when considering that I would like it to be a widget.

Hopefully Google will develop (if they somehow aren't already) a translation tool to accomplish this task, but until this, I'm out of ideas.

So here are some questions:

---

Are there any conversion tools for this yet?  Something that would allow you use a program and/or a web service to point to the XML file used for the iGoogle gadget and have the program/service return back the necessary project files needed fro Android apps?

I'm not sure if this approach mentioned above is at all possible, but I'm sure that an Android app can be developed to perform the same way as it does on iGoogle - it's pretty basic Javascript + CSS syntax.

In any case, where should I start and what tutorials (if any) exist with regards to this specific request of translating iGoogle gadgets into Android apps (preferably avoiding the "iframe" type of app framework that just points to the mobile version of a webpage).

---

Are my assumptions $| intentions out of scope here?  I feel like this is an easily doable project via the traditional means of using Androids SDK with Eclipse, for example.  I tried messing around with the online GUI that Google had for developing Android apps, but the programming interface was like Visual Basic for 3rd graders - it just wasn't too intuitive either.

Also, any other suggestions on what steps I could take to execute this task would be greatly appreciated.  I'm just guessing on how this could be done potentially, but if anyone has done something like this already or has insight towards this conversion process that's more valuable than pure speculation as I was doing above, please answer back with some suggestions as to how to accomplish this iGoogle Gadget -> Android Application conversion process.

---

---

I found another somewhat similar question on SO, but it doesn't have the same end result that I'm looking for: [iGoogle Gadget on Android Phone as APP or Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044429/igoogle-gadget-on-android-phone-as-app-or-widge)

---

---

Thanks a bunch for any help!

Answer (score 1):

So far there is no conversion tool that allows converting to an Android wiget a preexisting widget written for another system. You have to rewrite it.

I know some code generators exist, but I don't know them. They won't take the gadget you are referring to as a source, but maybe they can help you to redesign it for Android. This requires checking.

Comment: thanks - where can i find the code generators and/or any guides/tutorials for their intended purose?

Comment: I've heard about this one, but other may exist: http://appinventor.googlelabs.com - I've never tried

Comment: That was recently given the axe