# Still no ways to convert an iGoogle gadget into an Android (home screen) widget?

Tags: android, android-widget, google-gadget, igoogle

I want to convert existing Google Gadgets to Android home-screen widgets.

I found similar questions.

- [How do I convert an iGoogle gadget into an Android widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6844886/how-do-i-convert-an-igoogle-gadget-into-an-android-widget)
- [iGoogle Gadget on Android Phone as APP or Widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044429/igoogle-gadget-on-android-phone-as-app-or-widget)

About 2 years have passed since the above questions posted.

Is there still no way **to convert (i)Google Gadgets into Android home-screen widgets?**

Comment: What have you tried yet? This site is about programming so if you are a normal customer please go on [android.SE]

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply. I'm a developer, not consumer. I have already made a google gadget. I want to make it possible to use it on android home screen, hopefully without rewriting them in android.